# How to refresh a kendo ui grid inside a partial view without reloading the entire page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Good day,

I am having a tough time refreshing just the kendo grid that is placed inside a partial view. Take a look at the code I am currently using in my partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TelerikMvcAscernAdmin2.Models.ConnectionViewModel>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("id").Sortable().Columns(c =>  {
  c.Bound(p => p.SystemId);
  c.Bound(p => p.Host);
  c.Bound(p => p.Port);})
  .DataSource(datasoure =>datasoure.Server().PageSize(25).Sort(sort=>{sort.Add(c => c.Host).Ascending(); })
                  ).Filterable()
  .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new int[] { 25, 35, 40 })
        .Refresh(true)).Groupable().Sortable().Scrollable(s => s.Height("200px")).RowAction(row =>   {
  if (row.DataItem.Port == 0) row.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background:red";  }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 800px;" }) )

<script>  $(document).ready(function () {
          var refId = setInterval(function () {
          var grid = $("#id").data("kendoGrid");
          grid.dataSource.read();
          }, 40000);
          });   </script>
```

As you can see, I am using a server side function so that I can auto-refresh this grid. I have tried switching it to an Ajax function, but when I do that my grid can't be refreshed.

I am rendering this partial view inside my Home view, as shown below:

```
@Html.Action("EngineConnection", "GatewayConnections")
```

Also, take a look at my action controller method, I am returning all my data to a partial view:

```
public ActionResult EngineConnection()
    {
        var gatewayConnections = GatewayConnections.GetAllConnections();
        var agents = Agent.RetrieveAgents();
        var connectionViewModels = (from agent in agents.Where(a => a.Active)
                                    join gatewayConnection in gatewayConnections on agent.SystemId equals gatewayConnection.ClientId into
                                        agentConnections
                                    from agentConnection in agentConnections.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    select
                                        new ConnectionViewModel
                                        {
                                            SystemId = agent.SystemId,
                                            Host = (agentConnection == null ? string.Empty : agentConnection.Host),
                                            Port = (agentConnection == null ? 0 : agentConnection.Port)
                                        }).ToList();
        return PartialView("_EngineConnection", connectionViewModels);
    }
```

I have tried returning a JSON object, but that does not seem to do the trick. Is there a way to refresh just the grid, instead of the entire page, and still keep the grid inside the partial view?

Any suggestion will help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you following way to bind the grid.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EntityStandardGridModel>()
    .Name("KendoEntityStandardGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
      {
         //columns
      })
      .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
      .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
      .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
      .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(100)
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.SearchId))
          .Read(read => read.Action("GetStandardGriddata", "Search", new { SearchId = Model.SearchId }))
        )
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tried binding the grid as you suggested. On page load all the data is present in the grid, but when I refresh just the grid, all my information disappears from the grid. I am wondering if it has something to do with the action method.

Comment: After further review the method that Ganesh provided seems to be the best option, I would just have to create a different method that would render the information in JSON format, and point to it in my read action.